# How to find matching routes in graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-theory, graph-databases

I`m creating web app that joins fellow-travelers. So, Person1 planning his ride from point A to point E through points B, C, D (A->B->C->D->E).  This route discribed in graph database neo4j and it has relevant nodes A, B, C, D, E and relations that connects points. Other Person2 planning his ride, and he also would be passing through poinds C and D. So, their routes matches in nodes C and D (they moves in one direction). Existing cypher queries allows to find separate nodes, and nodes connected an equal relations. Are there any algorithms, that allows to find more than two nodes connected in one path?

I`m using cypher-manual on neo4j website, but there is no any methods, that allows to solve my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to write your own code.  Straighforward:

```
Loop over every pair of routes
    Loop over every pair of nodes in route pair
        IF identical nodes
             add node to matched route
             set flag1 false
             set flag2 true
             WHILE flag2 is true
                set flag2 false
                IF subsequent nodes are equal
                    add node to matched route
                    set flag1 true
                    set flag2 true
             IF flag1 true
                 Output matched route
```

Comment: Perhaps this is an optimal decision and I thought about it. Wanted to make sure I wasn't missing any of the built-in graph database methods for looking up variants